# Raspberry Pi 3 AutoLogin doesn't work

Tags: pi-3, raspi-config, login

I recently updated my Raspberry Pi 3 (non b+) from Raspbian Jessie to Stretch and then to buster (it's also rocking Retropie 4.7.1 on top of that).

And for some reasons the autologin function : `raspi-config -> "3 Boot Options" -> "B1 Desktop / CLI" -> "B2 Console Autologin"` doesn't work anymore. Whenever I boot the pi it asks me for a login / password.

However the option `"B4 Desktop Autologin"` works just fine, but that's not what I want...

Any ideas of what could be going on there ? What log to take a look at ?

Thanks for reading

EDIT : Additional information, `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service` seems to have been edited correcty by raspi-config as I can read read the following line in it : `ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I $TERM`

Comment: If you choose to "upgrade" DESPITE the Foundation warning you are on your own. Skipping a release just makes it worse. It is faster to do a fresh install rather than patch.

Comment: I didn't skip a version.... I updated jessie -> buster , buster -> stretch... I have tons of stuff already installed and tweaked it would take me days to reconfigure everything. Also I don't have a direct line with the foundation nor did they sent me a mail warning me about anything. It didn't destroy my debian to upgrade major versions for the past 10 years or so.
Thanks for that constructive comment.

Comment: Did you really end up with Stretch? That's the version *before* Buster... Agree with the comment above though

Comment: good catch I had the order wrong writing this. I did Jessie -> Stretch -> Buster obviously. That would be weird otherwise indeed.

Comment: Please keep an eye on the Pi blog for upgrade advice - see https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/buster-the-new-version-of-raspbian/ it states **our recommendation is that you download a new clean image** and **We do not recommend upgrading an existing Stretch (or earlier) system to Buster** Too many changes happen that cannot be replicated by others to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm still trying to figure it out why the raspi-config edited line doesn't work.

But using : `ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi %I` in `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service` seems to be working just fine.

I'll update later if I find any reasons for why the other parameters are not working as I'm running out of time for today.

EDIT : I quickly reintroduced every single parameter given by raspi-config ... and now they all work. I didn't do anything else than remove them, and add them back one by one ... So I don't know.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.